# Is MiGLayout going to be included in Java 7?

Tags: java, miglayout, java-7

All I could find so far is this (open) Sun bug/RFE entry with **<strike>426</strike> 506** votes:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6530906

It's in third place in the [list of RFEs](http://bugs.sun.com/top25_rfes.do).

Tons of people have stated that it will be included in Java 7...but does anyone have any clear information on whether [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com) will be included?

---

**Answered**

Well, it seems Chad has a point - it's not on any official list anywhere, and time is sure ticking away, so unless something big happens, it's safe to say **MiGLayout apparently will not be included in Java 7**, literally in [spite](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enDE353DE353&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define:spite&esrch=FT1) of 426 votes from the community. Too bad.

Comment: Good excuse to start voting for it to be included if it isn't.

Comment: Of course if it really isn't included...you might wonder "Why vote at all?" if an RFE with 425 votes is not included.

Comment: The RFE has the status of "Accepted". I had assumed that meant it was going to be included. Does it not?

Comment: No. "In Progress" would mean it will be included. "Accepted" basically means "acknowledged"...

Comment: Would have been a much more useful addition than closures *sigh*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to keep up on JDK 7 news ([here's a good tumblr blog on it](http://java7.tumblr.com/)) and I actually hadn't heard about it.  [this post](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/top-10-features-of-jdk-7/) goes over some of the enhancements in JDK7 as of October 2009, and it doesn't mention MigLayout. Here's what it says on swing:

> *10. Swing updates
>
> There would be small additions to the Swing API including the JXLayer component decorator, JXDatePicker, and possibly CSS-based styling. JXLayer allows users to easily decorate the compound components and catch all Mouse, Keyboard and FocusEvent for all its subcomponents.*

That was back in October.  The biggest news on JDK7 is the [Inclusion of closures](http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/closures_qa).  They were proposed but then dropped.  But in November (after Oracle bought Sun) they got put back in. That pushed the [deadline back](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk7-dev/2009-November/001054.html) to september of this year (it was going to be out this quarter)

[here's a complete list of JDK7 featuers](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/).  I don't see MiGlayout anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it, therefore I don't think so. (Looking at a 30 day old version of JDK 1.7.0)